# how to combine multiple request loop in forkJoin, is it possible?

Tags: rxjs, observable, fork-join

i have observables like:

```
let obs1$ = of(problemsIds).pipe(flatMap(el => 
  return forkJoin(el.map(id => 
    this.projectsService.getProblemsChanges(+id)))))
let obs2$ = of(versionsIds).pipe(flatMap(el => 
  return forkJoin(el.map(id => 
    this.projectsService.getVersionById(+id)))))
```

then i want to get em in parallel:

```
return forkJoin([obs1$, obs2$])
```

and nothing happens.

But when ive done it with 1 obs(anyone of em), it does the result.

Why i cant combine it like that and how can i achieve it?

p.s. i know that i have to send requests as array of ids, but im interested of this case. thx

Comment: By "nothing happens" you mean that you don't get any results in the `subscribe`? Do you see any activity made by `getProblemsChanges` or `getVersionById`?

Comment: @Kos By "nothing happens" you mean that you don't get any results in the subscribe - true. It doesnt send anything of these.

Comment: `forkJoin` will emit only if all your Observables complete. See this [forkJoin example](https://observable-playground.github.io/rxjs/forkJoin/) for details. It might so happen that one of your requests doesn't complete. Try substituting `forkJoin`s with simple `merge`s (`import { merge } from 'rxjs'`) to see if everything other works.

Answer (score 0):

The below should work for you. Please try.

```
const obs1$ = this.problemIds.map(id => this.service.getProblemsChanges(+id));
const obs2$ = this.versionIds.map(id => this.service.getVersionById(+id));
return forkJoin(forkJoin(obs1$), forkJoin(obs2$)).subscribe(data => console.log(data));
```

Comment: it doesn't work( i tried it first, then i did what i provided here. Only concat's done the job, but it returns only the last obs(versions).

Comment: If you put your sample code somewhere on plunker or similar, I can try it out and help further.

Comment: hm, my code is working, but in my project it doesnt..look at:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-4cprbb?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

your code is returing observables

in my project ive used http against mock-data...

Comment: @DenKerny I have updated my answer with a fix. I was missing internal forkjoins. Verified on your stackblitz as well. Hope that helps.